# Is there any software for tracking TV shows?

Tags: software-recommendation, tv

I'm looking for a software to track my favorite TV shows on Ubuntu 13.04 to know when next episodes will be on air.

Is there any to recommend me?

Comment: Just in case you don't find a local solution here are some online show trackers: http://www.showmaniac.org/ http://www.sidereel.com/ https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/showmaniac/pbhgjcebcjcnenkmgdajaifiolgbnmih

Comment: I have been able to find these two offline tools for the job: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tvcmd/ and https://github.com/aleximplode/Show-Tracker. If someone's got more time on their hands feel free to compile a proper answer with instructions on how to use these.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess the best way is those websites and import the schedule in calendar